# Merecasters in Numenera

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

I got to necropolis and I got my hands on things called [merecasters](http://numenera.gamepedia.com/Floral_Merecaster) that let you 'experience' an episode of someone else's live...

Do they serve any other purpose - like can I get skills for them or quests or something?
Or after doing the story I should just sell them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of them are self contained stories with no effect on the game. Think of them as little gamebooks. You will get some experience for completing them, but that's about it.

Sadly none of the amazing places (I especially liked that town on top of a whale) or legacy you leave behind from completing a merecaster is seen anywhere in the game, so you won't notice the consequences of your choices within the mere.

There are a few merecasters related to the main story, you can easily notice them by having to complete them to progress (I think, there are 3 of those). Those will have consequences in the real world after you finished them.

The merecaster object itself can be sold freely after you completed your adventure in the mere.

Comment: Does it affect in anyway storywise or gives more or less XP how you respond to the things that happen inside the merecaster?